# Regex required for matching isloated % within a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to replace all "%" with "%%" in my string. However, my string might also have "%{abc}" and this shouldn't be replaced.

> Input: My name is %{name} and my % score is %{percentage} %!
>
> Output: My name is %{name} and my %% score is %{percentage} %%!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex to match all `%` not succeeded by `{`

```
s.gsub(/%(?!\{)/, '%%')
```

**EDIT**

To prevent replacement of `%%` (to `%%%%`):

```
s.gsub(/(?<!%)%(?![{%])/, '%%')
```

Note that this will prevent replacement of `%%%`, just in case some other behaviour is expected.

Credit goes to @MichaelKohl for gsub. @ZainZafar (OP) for the complete solution.

Comment: Hooray for negative lookaheads!

Comment: Maybe add the complete answer for the replacement: `s.gsub(/%(?!\{)/, '%%')`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just one minor issue is that it replace %% with %%%%. I know I didn't mention this case in the question but if you can please modify your answer to include that case?